# Delete an item from an array from collectionView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have this collection view with an array to be displayed as a menu: (I've been searching all Stack Overflow and none of the answers are working for me)

```
 //what cell to be displyed when and if
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = optionsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! OptionsCell

    let optionsForCell = self.options[indexPath.item]
    cell.option = optionsForCell

    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != cellUserIDa {


        if optionsForCell.optionName == "Edit Comment" {
            cell.isHidden = true
            options.remove(at: 0)
            print(optionsForCell)
        } else if optionsForCell.optionName == "Delete Comment" {
            cell.isHidden = true
            print(optionsForCell)
        }
    }
```

And the array:

```
var options : [Options] = {
        return [Options(optionName: "Edit Comment", optionImage: "edit2"),
                Options(optionName: "Delete Comment", optionImage: "trash"),
                Options(optionName: "Flag as Inappropriate", optionImage: "view"),
                Options(optionName: "Cancel", optionImage: "cancel")]
    }()
```

How do I delete one of the items from this array from the collectionView? I proactively want to delete the cell also, so if any better ways to do it?

Comment: aaah, the typical collection view deletion question :D, I'll post an answer soon, since it's a handful of code that goes in, stay tuned.

Comment: I am staying tuned as I am stuck at this part... :)

Comment: oh btw, do you just want to remove from the array or are you looking for something like swipe to delete feature in tableview for the collection view with some animation going on ?

Comment: I just want to remove it from the array so my collection view will show only the ones remaining. It is actually a menu that will display for current user the whole menu and for a visitor less options. I was also thinking at grading them out in the menu like a disable but I don't think it works with the options that I have.

Comment: so basically you want to have separate menu data for visitor and the user ?

Comment: Yes. For the user will be all 4 of them and for the visitor only 2 of them.

Comment: and for that case I guess the data is static and not dynamic (coming from JSON)

Comment: Yes it's static. Most exactly the array in my question!

Comment: that's pretty straight forward then. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thanks! It works well like this, sorry for late response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as discussed you have two scenarios 
1) Menu for the Visitor
2) Menu for the User

Since the data is static and not dynamic and keeping things simple. Let's have two arrays named respectively:-

```
var visitors =["Daily", "Monthly", "Yearly"]

var users = ["Daily", "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Yearly"]
```

From your code I can figure out you are checking if the person is actually a user or visitor by authenticating, use this same logic when you are populating the collection view cells. This will save you from the hassles of deleting and adding from the array for two different types of persons.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = optionsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! OptionsCell

if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != cellUserIDa {

// visitor, do the visitor stuff 
cell.optionLabel.text = visitors[indexPath.row]
}
else {
// user, do the usr stuff

cell.optionLabel.text = users[indexPath.row]
}

}
```

the same thing goes for the other two delegate functions for collectionView. Return the count of visitor if the person is not authenticated else return the count of user. This will save you a lot of time by not deleting and hiding the unwanted cells.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the item from the array by giving the index of item you want to delete eg.
animals.remove(at: 2)
when the item is been deleted just reload the collectionView
eg . collectionView.reload()

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best sample code according to your requirement. first you need to set your options according to your users the demo gives you more clear idea for that.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xh4pxtghy8696nj/DemoCollectionView.zip?dl=0